# Angular CustomValueAccesor - input value is not refreshing, when model make changes to value

Tags: javascript, angular, ngmodel, controlvalueaccessor

problem playground:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nuggp

Steps:

1. set input value to `-1` and blur - `handleBlur` is triggered, model make `Math.abs` on the value, `writeValue` is triggered and input value is set to `1` - correct
2. again set input value to `-1` and blur -`handleBlur` is triggered, model make `Math.abs` on the value, but writeValue is not triggered, and input value stays `-1`

I guess that i know what's going on - on step 2 writeValue is not triggered, becouse after `math.abs` value is same that after step 1.

But i have no idea how to fix this problem.
I've tried to somehow reset value inside valueAccessor (fe. using `ngControl.control.setValue`), but without success.

Answer (score 1):

i updated the code to solve this problem, you need always to set the value to the ngModel control because if the value become 1 from -1 the ngModel ctrl still see the -1 as last value in this case update always the ngModel and it will resolve the problem and don't forget to set `emitViewToModelChange` to false while updating the value or you will get in infinity calls!!

[here is the updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slx8xh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for replay! Solution looks pretty gut, but if fe. i have 5 different components using input component in same way (math.abs), that i need to implement this solution in every component. I looking for a more complex solution. Maybe some kind od additional directive to input component. Or some way to fix this in controlValueAccessor